# LinkOpen::links: Too many open links. >> error

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

I am opening iteratively an external program (executable) by using LinkOpen[].
After a certain number of iterations (more than 1000), I get the following error:

```
LinkOpen::links: Too many open links. >>
```

and my notebook stops working (calling the external program). Actually, I realize that I am opening many connection to the external program and this could be the problem. 
The question is: how can I monitor the open connection and, also, close them all?

thanks

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you are doing? I do not understand "I am opening iteratively an external program (executable) by using LinkOpen[].".  That is not what LinkOpen is for.

Comment: "Since Version 3.0 (released in 1996), LinkOpen has been superseded" ...

Comment: what I am doing is something like:

Do[
LinkOpen[pathexecutable],
{i,1,n}]

for very large values of n, I get the error mentioned in the title

Comment: @Luigi That does not explain much ... Why are you passing the path to an executable to LinkOpen?  What do you believe LinkOpen does?  You are very likely misusing this function.  Please edit the question and describe in detail what commands you are using and *what you are hoping to achieve with them*.

Comment: I did not know that LinkOpen has been superseded. How to run an external executable then?

Comment: The purpose of LinkOpen has never been running executables.  Why do you think it is?  Where did you find this function, and why did you start using it?

Comment: @Szabolcs: {}, what I am doing is run an executable and pass a bunch of parameters to it (par1, par2,..) 
LinkOpen[executable -par1 -par2 -...]
and I repeat this a number of times. I am using this function to process 2D images since many years and only now, when the number of images became really high I noticed this error. What function is most appropriate for this kind of use?

Comment: The function to *run* an executable is `Run` (or more recently `RunProcess`). I am still confused about your question: if you are not using MathLink, why did you tag it with [tag:mathlink-or-wstp]?  And if really isn't about MathLink, how did you come to believe that `LinkOpen` was for running processes?